# Trying to "Include" a .ASP file in a .VBS file

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a .VBS file that runs via scheduled task on my server.  I have some data in a .ASP file that resides on my website that I want to pull in to that .VBS file so that I do not need to duplicate the same info in two places.

Here is a sample of the data in the ASP file:

```
<%
If MyVar = "1" Then
    Data1 = "this"
    Data2 = "that"
Else 
    Data1 = "hi"
    Data2 = "there"
End If
%>
```

Is this possible?  I think I recall something about ExecuteGlobal, but cannot put it all together - if that in fact can help here.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  So i just strip the <% and %> and then I can ExecuteGlobal the leftover text and I will have access to the variables after that?  Sample data above.   thx!

Answer (score 4):

`ExecuteGlobal ValidVBSCode` is the easy way to re-use/import/include VBScript **code** into W/CScript hosted scripts. The problem with ASP code are the "<% ... %>", so you have to pre-process the **code** loaded by `.Readall()`.

As you mention '**data** in a .ASP file' an alternative approach may be to **.ReadAll()** the file as text and **parse** the info into a suitable (perhaps complex) variable.

If you need more help, publish a small but representative sample of the file to be 'included'.

**Demo script (for the given sample):**

```
Option Explicit

Dim sASP : sASP = Join(Array( _
     " <% If MyVar = ""1"" Then" _
   , "       Data1 = ""this""" _
   , "       Data2 = ""that""" _
   , "   Else" _
   , "       Data1 = ""hi""" _
   , "       Data2 = ""there""" _
   , "   End If %>" _
), vbCrLf)
WScript.Echo sASP

Dim sExpr : sExpr = Replace(Replace(sASP, "<%", ""), "%>", "")
WScript.Echo sExpr
Dim MyVar, Data1, Data2
For Each MyVar In Split("1 2")
    ExecuteGlobal sExpr
    WScript.Echo myVar, Data1, Data2
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 22821687.vbs
 <% If MyVar = "1" Then
       Data1 = "this"
       Data2 = "that"
   Else
       Data1 = "hi"
       Data2 = "there"
   End If %>
  If MyVar = "1" Then
       Data1 = "this"
       Data2 = "that"
   Else
       Data1 = "hi"
       Data2 = "there"
   End If
1 this that
2 hi there
```

**Update wrt to comments and @Dennis' demo code:**

I wrongly assumed (based on w/cscript rejecting them) that "<%..%>" would cause problems. As Dennis' code demonstrates (and my 'after the reading' tests confirm), Execute(Global) handles them well; the replace(s) aren't necessary. (So I think Dennis' answer deserves credit.)

Comment: Question - where is the import from the ASP file?  Or is that where the ReadAll call using FSO comes in?  Also, not sure I understand the Split.  Thanks so much for the help - appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, the problem with this answer is that it omits the actual possibly-hard step: importing the contents of the .asp file. "How do I import data from another file?" "Well, once you have the data, here is how you can use it."

Comment: @Martha - that's why I mentioned .ReadAll() twice. Furthermore: the OT explicitly asked about ExecuteGlobal and its use. What ails me: My worries about the "<%..%>" were wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I did test that code again with and without the replace and it does work.  So, it is not needed.  Thanks for helping me figure out a way to include ASP files in a VBS file!

Answer (score 3):

Got this working!  Here is a sample bit of code.  THANKS for the help!

```
MyVar = "2"
Sub Import(ByVal strFile)
   Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set objFile = objFs.OpenTextFile(strFile)
   strCode = objFile.ReadAll
   objFile.Close
   ExecuteGlobal(strCode)
End Sub
Import "E:\path\test.asp"
msgbox(Data1)
```

And the response is "hi".

Comment: Why was my working answer voted down?  Also, the comments that I was emailed are all not showing on this thread.  Odd.

Comment: This meta thread will provide you with the necessary context, Dennis. Personally I add my working solution as a "Community Wiki" answer when the solution has been greatly provided by another answer, you might be interested in this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228219/should-this-answer-be-removed

Comment: Guess someone decided to delete them, don't agree with that personally I'd rather my comments were left alone or I was at least notified.